# How can I get notified via E-mail for new answers to my question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I want to get notified for new answers to my question on Stack Overflow via E-mail. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Would digest's be ok? Or answers to a specific question?

Comment: Answers to questions posted by 'me'.

Comment: Is that all questions posted by you in general, or just for certain tags or websites?